# How to get height of element with position fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to get the height of an element with position fixed?

**code:**

```
elm.outerHeight(true)
```

this code will return 0 when the position is set to fixed

Comment: Put your code within document ready handler or window load handler http://jsfiddle.net/p6gvH/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `.height()` with fixed position elements too, as in:

```
var h = $('div').height();
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/C2s8T/ - works in FF and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
     getComputedStyle(div).position
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [jQuery.offset();](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) for this.

Like `$("div.container").offset().top;` or `$("div.container").offset().left;`

Comment: No, it returns the position of the element, not its height.